# Url change in a html form using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom

I'm working with the value of a variable in a JS file in a function in charged of updating values in a html table without the need of reloading the website as follows:

```
function updateTabla(plan, plan_valor, total_valor, descuento_nombre, descuento_valor, callback) {

if (descuento_nombre != 0) {
    $(".txt-descuento").removeClass('sr-only');
    $(".txt-descuento-nombre").html("Descuento: "+descuento_nombre);
    $(".txt-descuento-valor").html("$ "+descuento_valor.toLocaleString()+" (COP)");
}

if ($("#codigo_actual").data('valor') != 0) {

    total_valor = plan_valor - $("#codigo_actual").data('valor');

    $(".txt-descuento").removeClass('sr-only');
    $(".txt-descuento-nombre").html($("#codigo_actual").val());
    $(".txt-descuento-valor").html($("#codigo_actual").data('valor'));
}

$(".txt-plan").html(plan);
$(".txt-valor").html("$ "+plan_valor.toLocaleString()+" (COP)");
$(".txt-total-valor").html("$ "+total_valor.toLocaleString()+" (COP)");

$("#amount").val(total_valor);

if(total_valor === 0){
    var num = 'si ejecuta';

    $("#frm-pago").removeAttr('url');
    $("#frm-pago").attr({
    url: www.prueba2.com;
    });
}

console.log(total_valor);

console.log(num);

callback();
}
```

What I need is: using an If statement with "total_valor" make an action. The action I need is to modify a url in an html form inside of a php file. I am trying to modify the url attribute in the form like this:

```
$("#frm-pago").removeAttr('url');
$("#frm-pago").attr({
  url: www.prueba2.com;
});
```

I need somebody's help that let me know what am I doing wrong or is there something else that I can try since the data in the JS is being well processed, when I check the values using console.log(total_valor) and console.log(num) I get the values that I want but can't change the html form.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Form elements do not have a `url` attribute … did you mean the `action` perhaps? And btw., using `removeAttr` is not necessary if you want to _change_ the value, simply overwriting it will do.

Comment: Thank you CBroe! That solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form elements do not have a `url` attribute - looks like you meant the `action` attribute instead.

And btw., using `removeAttr` is not necessary if you want to change the value, simply overwriting it will do.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#frm-pago").attr("url", "www.prueba2.com");
```